# load more items than visible in android listview

Tags: android

In android I have a listview, with images that i am loading from urls using picasso. The problem i have is that i want picasso to start loading the images before the listview item comes into view so that it has a better chance of being loaded by the time the user sees it. The problem is it only starts loading when the listview item is right under the view so most of the time the user sees the place holder image. Is there any good way to start loading images sooner so that there is less time waiting? i dont want to download all the images at once as soon as the data is loaded though because that slows down everything. Any advice?

Comment: try to Disk Cache with picaso..

Answer (score 0):

With Picaso you can use **fetch()** function load to cache before display:

```
Picasso.with(activity).load(imageUrl).fetch();
```

Comment: the problem is when do i do this? I dont want to do this as soon as i get all my data becaues that could mean loading 30 pictures that the user never sees

Comment: you can load some picture before you scroll to there. You don't need load all.

Comment: exactly thats the question how do i load pictures before i scroll there

Comment: You know viewpager ? data you save in a list. when you scroll to position i you can use fetch() to load i, i+ 1, i + 2.

Comment: hmm does it matter that this will be calling fetch on the same picture 3 times. its not going to make that many actual requests is it? because then it would call fetch for i-2, i-1, and then call get on i

Comment: when you call fetch() the picture have been cache so that when you recall it don't need load from server. I don't know what the matter that you don't understand here.